# DIV covering over the login buttons in commons-origins theme

Tags: theming, 7

We're using Commons 3. It uses a sub-theme of Adaptive Themes (AT). There appears to be a DIV that is blocking users from clicking on the signup | login area.

Should I file a bug on this or work around it with CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a work around.

```
#block-search-form  .block-inner {
    height: 30px;
}
```